# Compile R package "arulesSequence" for older release

Tags: r, oracle, arules

I want to use [arulessequences](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesSequences/index.html) for sequence mining.  I have to use it in Oracle R distribution version R 3.3.0 (last released) and The problem is that the last version of the arulesSequences package is R >= 3.3.2. So I get an error for this problem:

> Error: this is R 3.3.0, package arulesSequences needs >=3.3.2

So I decided to compile the source code for older release. I downloaded an older package that needs R 3.2.5 or above. And I know that this package is depended to arules. so I have installed it already.  I used following instructions to compile the arulessequences package:
in the source directory I run this command:

> R CMD build arulesSequences
>   the output of this command is:
>
> c:\rr\arulesSequences_0.2-17>R CMD build arulesSequences
>   * checking for file 'arulesSequences/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
>   * preparing 'arulesSequences':
>   * checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
>   * cleaning src Warning in cleanup_pkg(pkgdir, Log) :   unable to run 'make clean' in 'src'
>   * checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
>   * checking for empty or unneeded directories
>   * looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
>   * building 'arulesSequences_0.2-17.tar.gz'

a file named 'arulesSequences_0.2-17.tar.gz' get created but when I check it as below I get the following as output:

> c:\rr\arulesSequences_0.2-17\arulesSequences>R CMD check arulesSequences
>   * using log directory 'c:/rr/arulesSequences_0.2-17/arulesSequences/arulesSequences.Rcheck'
>
> - using R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
> - using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
> - using session charset: ISO8859-1
> - checking for file 'arulesSequences/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
> - this is package 'arulesSequences' version '0.2-17'
> - checking package namespace information ... OK
> - checking package dependencies ... ERROR   Package required but not available: 'arules'
>
> See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
>   manual.
>   * DONE   Status: 1 ERROR

I know the arules package is installed and I checked it. It seems the build process is not successful. do you have any idea to help solve this out?

Comment: "And I know that this package is depended to arules." . What package is that ?

Comment: arulesSequences is depended on arules, I have installed arules befor installing arulesSequences.

Comment: I think I had to rewrite this package on my own !!

Comment: I don't understand too much why you are proceeding this way, I will post an answer that I have tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first install c/c++ compiler for R(called gcc) that is under R's additional build tools.
to do that, in RStudio goto File->New File ->c++ File.
It will show the following dialogue:
[image]
Then click on yes.
to compile a package under windows, you have to set repo to Null and type to source.
you can use this command to do that:

```
install.packages("SOURCEADDRESS",type="source",repo=null)
```

as @EugèneAdell mentioned above you have to first install arules. then arulessequences.

Comment: I have installed the RBuildTools as you mentioned and now everything works fine. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building, take the archive packages that seem to be ok for your R version and install them. On my Linux, this gives :

```
wget http://cran.univ-paris1.fr/src/contrib/Archive/arules/arules_1.5-0.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL $HOME/arules_1.5-0.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/home/ruser/R-3.2.5/lib64/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘arules’ ...
...
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (arules)

wget http://cran.univ-paris1.fr/src/contrib/Archive/arulesSequences/arulesSequences_0.2-17.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL $HOME/arulesSequences_0.2-17.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/home/ruser/R-3.2.5/lib64/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘arulesSequences’ ...
...
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (arulesSequences)

R
> library(arulesSequences)
Loading required package: arules
Loading required package: Matrix

Attaching package: ‘arules’
```

Maybe a more recent version for arules is possible, I just took the first one from the 1.5 series.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am working in Windows, I just tried to installed and it failed with this error:  Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/R/oracle/R-3.3.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/R/oracle/R-3.3.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="arules.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="arrayIndex.o bitmat.o istree.o matrix.o ptree.o rapriori.o reclat.o similarity.o symtab.o tfscan.o tid_count.o tract.o vecops.o warm.o"' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'arules'
* removing 'C:/R/oracle/R-3.3.0/library/arules'

Comment: If you compile & install an ordinary package, does it work ?

Comment: No, I tested it for another package, named GLUE, but the same error!, maybe its reason is that I am using Oracle R distribution, cause I want to integrate R with Oracle database, what do you think?

Comment: Same problem with the standard version of R, I am not sure what is the problem, did you tested your solution on Windows platform ?

Comment: I can't test here at work, but later maybe (it's a long work to reproduce your problem). Did you read carefully the documentation : https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Windows-packages ? If it's a permission issue, is there anything in the event viewer log ?